# Make Ubuntu 20.04 look exactly like 18.04

Tags: 20.04

I want the dynamic panel and dock transparency, the Ambiance shell theme, and I already got the app theme, but the app theme is all I can get. I really love how 18.04 looks, and I really want to get it back.

Comment: Ambiance shell theme?? Are you sure?

Comment: See [here](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-get-gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-20-04/). And [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2588/fully-transparent-top-bar/) for the transparent bar.

Comment: Please edit your Question to add the version of `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` that you are trying to get back. Depending when you downloaded it, 18.04 could have come with any one of many possible versions. If you add the version and let me know with \@NateT i can add the commands you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

As `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is downloadable via Apt, it is possible to download a different version. However, to put it mildly, there may be some issues along the way. If i were you, I would download the newest 18.04-based version possible, as that will give the best chance of experiencing the least amount of issues.

If you do decide to go this route, I would recommend thoroughly reading the man-pages for `apt-src` and `dpkg-source` at the very least. If it were me personally, I would type in `man apt-`  and double tap  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  so I could see my options. If you do the same with dpkg, you will find quite a few of them. Common sense will tell you which will be the most beneficial.

At any rate, a single version swap is fairly easy to undo. This is why I suggested `man`. Any time you hack your system in this fashion, you need to first ensure *beforehand* that you are able to easily undo any changes.

I personally don't think this will be a big deal. I completely removed (more like unloaded) both  GNOME and X11 both on 20.04, and had my system running smoothly under Wayland / Sway WM within fifteen minutes or so. However I spent a lot more than that on preparation.

Last but not least (maybe most,) **CREATE A FULL BACKUP** before trying it. There are A LOT of apps / packages / functionalities that depend on GNOME.. A LOT. I spent ages just getting back small features (small when you have them) such as screen shots and brightness control. For a lot of features, the closest I got were workarounds, such as keymapping home-brewed sh scripts.